# How to modify bootstrap flash message in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem in bootstrap flash message . I have to change color for some text in flash message.

**Controller**

```
redirect_to complaints_path, notice: "Complaint was successfully created & Your Complaint Reference Id is #{@complaint.complaint_id}"
```

I have change color of the @complaint/complaint_id

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "danger" %>">
   <span class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</span>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It will display success message in green color. but i have change complaint_id alone red color..
Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

You can create an helper to deal with flash messages:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
    { success: "alert-success", error: "alert-danger", alert: "alert-warning", notice: "alert-info" }[flash_type] || flash_type.to_s
  end

  def flash_messages(opts = {})
    flash.each do |msg_type, message|
      concat(content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)} fade in") do 
              concat content_tag(:button, 'x', class: "close", data: { dismiss: 'alert' })
              concat message 
            end)
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Then in your application.html.erb layout use them:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

      <%= flash_messages %>

      <%= yield %>
    </div><!-- /container -->
</body>
```

If you don't want this DRY approach, you can adapt it to your needs.